# How to read application.properties value inside the constructor in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, autowired

I know Constructors are calling before the auto wiring the variables. But, unfortunately, I want to read the application.properties value inside the constructor?

```
@Component
public class DESedeEncryption {
  private static final String key = "TEST_KEY";
  public DESedeEncryption() {
    system.out.println(key);
 }
}

DESedeEncryption encrypted = new DESedeEncryption();
```

For the above class, the object has been created by using a new operator in my project totally 108 places. Now, I want to read that key value from the application.properties. But, I need to change all 108 places by using @Autowired annotation. But, some of the places the object creation written by using "new" operator in entity class files. So, I can't auto wired the object inside the entity class.

Someone, please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 10):

You can declare a variable inside the Constructor with @Value annotation, where you want call the application.properties variable.

Example class:

```
  public DESedeEncryption(@Value("${key}") final String key) {
    system.out.println(key);
 }
```

Comment: I tried this already. but Which value do I need to pass to the constructor when creating an object?
DESedeEncryption encrypted = new DESedeEncryption();
It gave compilation error.

Comment: there is one option you can follow,  Call a function inside the constructor, that functions gets the values from application.properties using @Value annotation and displays the key value.

Comment: Hope this help.

Comment: public class EncryptionConfig {
     
     Value("${app.encryption.key}")
     private String key;

     public String getKey() {
       return key;
     }
}

component
public class DESedeEncryption {
  
    Autowired
    private EncryptionConfig config;

   public DESedeEncryption() {
      System.out.println(config.getKey());
   }
}

Output is
null pointer exception returns null. Because, of " new DESedeEncryption()". Config object comes as a NULL.

Comment: try this logic 
component public class DESedeEncryption 
{ 
Value("${app.encryption.key}") 
private String key; 

public DESedeEncryption() { 

System.out.println(getKey()); 
} 

public String getKey()
 { return key; }
}

Comment: **On the application startup**
getKey() method returns NULL => Because, constructors are called before the auto wiring the variables

**when new DESedeEncryption()***
getKey() method returns  null. Because, global variables initialized with default values when creating a new object.

Comment: https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Super+simple+approach+to+accessing+Spring+beans+from+non-Spring+managed+classes+and+POJOs